# heroku run rake db:migrate gives rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sqlite, heroku-postgres

I'm new to ruby on rails, github and heroku. Now i am doing fixed deposit project in that project i am using database **sqlite3 in my localhost** and **postgres in heroku**.

I have add a field called **int** which datatype is **string** and i changed the datatype from **string** to **integer**. Finally, i decided to change it again from **integer** to **float**. 
In my local host its working perfecly. But, when i'm trying to run in heroku it shows rake aborted.

**heroku run rake db:migrate**

it shows the following error message

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.4356

Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL

Migrating to CreateFds (20140505120047)

Migrating to Changedatatypeforfd (20140506065307)


Migrating to AddMdToFds (20140506080333)

Migrating to AddIntToFds (20140506080404)

Migrating to Changedatatypeforint (20140506103001)

==  Changedatatypeforint: migrating ======================

-- change_column(:fds, :int, :integer)

rake aborted!

StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PGError: ERROR:  column "int" cannot be cast automatically to type integer

HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
: ALTER TABLE "fds" ALTER COLUMN "int" TYPE integer
```

my db files are listed below

**20140506080404_add_int_to_fds.rb**

```
class AddIntToFds < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change

    add_column :fds, :int, :string
  end

end
```

**20140506103001_changedatatypeforint.rb**

```
class Changedatatypeforint < ActiveRecord::Migration

 def up

    change_column :fds, :int, :integer

  end


  def down

    change_column :fds, :int, :string


  end

end
```

**20140508105541_rechangedatatypeforint.rb**

```
class Rechangedatatypeforint < ActiveRecord::Migration


  def up

    change_column :fds, :int, :float

  end


  def down

    change_column :fds, :int, :integer

  end

end
```

Sorry for my blunder.
Please give me the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The migration aborted because it treated int as a preserve name.

Comment: Bharat soni: How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku uses PostgreSQL. In PostgreSQL int is a reserved word, you cannot use it as a column name.
Use something else for your `int` name

```
change_column :fds, :valid_name, :integer
```

[SQL Key Words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

If you want to cast from float to integer, one way to do it is:

```
class MigrationNameHere < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute('ALTER TABLE fds ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE integer USING round(column_name);')
  end
end
```

This migration will convert all your float numbers to integer ones and it **is not reversible** so be careful. I advise you to have a backup before doing this.

Comment: Octopus-Paul: Thank you Sir.

Comment: Octopus-Paul: I want it as float. for that  change_column :fds, interest, :float. is it right?.

Comment: It is OK. Read about migrations http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

Comment: Octopus-Paul: Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Does your migrations run with success now on Heroku?

Comment: No, Still i'm facing that problem...:(

Comment: I updated the answer. Try now. Do a backup before if you have data in that table.

Comment: Ocopus-Paul: Sir, I go with another way. I have deleted the un wanted migration files from the git now my application working successfully in heroku. Thanks a lot for your support